# Animate div size transition with unknown sizes

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, transition

I would like to animate the transition of a div's size (`signupForm`) whose content changes dynamically.

The size of the container div in each step is unknown.

I would prefer to do this in CSS.

I'm using Vue.js to swap out the forms.

```
<div class="signupForm">
  <component id="currentView">
    <FormOne></FormOne>
    <FormTwo></FormTwo>
    <FormThree></FormThree>
    <FormFour></FormFour>
    <FormFive></FormFive>
  </component>
</div>
```

`#signupForm` never leaves, but `FormOne` gets swapped for `FormTwo`, etc.

I have added the following:

```
.signupForm {
  max-height:inherit;
  display:inline-block;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

But the transition property didn't help much. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is with `max-height: inherit;` 
Try to use some big value in px (`5000px` for example). The value that you think, you will never reach.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure `max-height` has transform possibility, Maybe this helps:

```
.signupForm {
  max-height:inherit;
  display:inline-block;
  transition: height 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```